# Am I being blocked by a website due to some missing parameters?( Scraping with selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

The page I'm trying to scrape (for practice) is the url below. I'm trying to scrape the income-statement (chart) on the bottom of the page

```
import time

from PIL import Image
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
browser.quit()
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.implicitly_wait(12)
url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/OPK/financials/income-statement'



browser.get(url)
time.sleep(9)
#x =browser.find_element_by_class_name('content')
y =browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='industrial-income-statement']")
```

This code was working just a little while ago; now I"m getting a "No such element" error, for this line  `y =browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='industrial-income-statement']")`

If I type `browser.page_source`:

There is something about *access being denied*, but I'm not exactly sure why.
I'm only trying to scrape one chart, and I'm using Selenium which I assumed has the appropriate headers.

`'0px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; "></textarea></div></div></div>\n          <p>\n            Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.\n          </p>\n          <p>\n            This may happen as a result of the following:\n          </p>\n          <ul>\n            <li>\n              Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)\n            </li>\n            <li>\n              Your browser does not support cookies\n            </li>\n          </ul>\n          <p>\n            Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking them from loading.\n          </p>\n          <p>\n            Reference ID: #a2a7fe90-4a2a-11e7-be16-a994e7f2d3b8\n          </p>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n      <div class="page-footer-wrapper">\n        <div class="page-foote`

PhantomJS doesn't block Javascript nor block cookies as far as I know.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should pretend not to be `PhantomJS` to avoid being detected:

```
capabilities = dict(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
capabilities["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

I would though be careful about scraping this resource without an explicit consent - check out [Terms of Use](https://seekingalpha.com/page/terms-of-use) - the "User Conduct" section.

Comment: Thank you =).   Who do I usually contact to get consent? I actually just want to scrape this one page for practicing purposes. (Lots of challenges due to how Javascript(?) is implemented).

Comment: @moondra well, they have "contact us" section with multiple options. But, since you are just doing it for a single page, I don't think you should really do it unless you are doing heavy web-scraping or gonna use the extracted data in an illegal manner :)